# Get $_SESSION position with &

Tags: php, session, reference, unset

Why this code doesn't work?

```
public function get($key) {
    return isset($_SESSION[$key]) ? &$_SESSION[$key] : false;
}
```

Error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' in C:\Arquivos de programas\EasyPHP-5.3.3\www\myphpblog\code\sessionstorage.class.php on line 12
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use `array_key_exist($key, $_SESSION)` if you want to allow for the possibility that `$_SESSION[$key]` has been previously set to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

A ternary operator is really three [expressions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php), e.g. *expr1 ? expr2 : expr3;*

See the [Notes in Returning References](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php):

> If you try to return a reference from a function with the syntax: `return ($this->value);` this will not work as you are attempting to return the result of an expression, and not a variable, by reference. You can only return variables by reference from a function - nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for returning a reference in PHP is `&<function name>(){ return <referece> }`
Also, `Only variable references should be returned by reference`

So, you should probably rewrite it:

```
function &get($key) {
    $a = false;
    if( isset($_SESSION[$key]) )
        return $_SESSION[ $key ];
    return $a;
}
```

Comment: That's... interesting. I've no real idea what returning a reference to a local variable will do in PHP, as I've never tried it. In most other languages it's a serious logic error.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the & and it will work. Dah...